# Draw a circle partially inside on a button dynamically android

Tags: android, button, layout, dynamic, geometry

My class Triangle extends from View and its method onDraw consists of:

```
   ... onDraw(){
   ...
  drawCircle(anyx, anyy, anyradius, anypaint);
  }
```

And the Activity in which I want to create the Button and the Circle, both created dynamically.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newexample);
    RelativeLayout viewGroup   = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.visiont);
    Button b1 = new Button(this);
    viewGroup.addView(b1);
    b1.setX(140); // Position of the button 
    b1.setY(140);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = b1.getLayoutParams();
    params.height=80; // Size of the button 
    params.width=80;
    b1.setLayoutParams(params); // Deleting this does not change the behaviour of what I am getting (only changes the height and width)
    Circle c = new Circle(this);
    c.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    c.setCircle(150,130,80);
    viewGroup.addView(c);
    }
```

An example of what is the desired result, the rectangle is the button.

[image: Desired result]

What I am getting now is the opposite, the button is over the circle.

[image: Result now]

Comment: try to add your circle first and then button to your relative layout

Comment: It does not work. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to switch Button to ImageButton since I wanted to have a custom image in the button (Actually I wanted a clickable component)

It appears that, with only switching Button to ImageButton, works as desired, so, for me it's a suitable solution.